# Kubectl : No resource found

Tags: kubectl, ibm-cloud-private, cloud-pak-for-data

I’ve installed `ICP4Data` successfully. I am pretty green in respect to `ICP4Data` and `Kubernetes`. I’m trying to use `kubectl` command for listing the pods in ICP4D but “kubectl get pods” returns *“No resource found”*. Am I missing something?

Comment: What output do you get from `kubectl cluster-info`? You might not be correctly configured to access the cluster. See [this kubernetes doc page](https://v1-10.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#configure-kubectl).
You might also need to specify a namespace in your command.

Answer (score 54):

icp4d uses 'zen' namespaces to logically separate its assets and resources from the core native icp/kube platform. In the default installation of ICP4D, there are no pods deployed on 'default' namespace and hence you get "no resources found" cause if you don't provide the namespace while trying to get pods, kubectl assumes its **default** namespace.

To List the pods from zen namespace

```
  kubectl get pods -n zen
```

To list all the namespaces available to you - try

```
kubectl get namespaces
```

To list pods from all the namespaces, you might want to append --all-namespaces

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

This should list all the pods from zen, kubesystem and possibly others.

Answer (score 8):

On the other hand, you could switch your namespace to zen at the beginning by

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=zen
```

Then you will be able to see all the information by running without the -n argument

```
kubectl get pods
```

Answer (score 6):

Please try adding namespace to the command as well. In the case for ICP4D try `kubectl get pods -n zen`.

Answer (score 3):

Check you are currently on which namespace.

To find out your pod is created in which namespace, you can run this command

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
```

Answer (score 2):

Also just to add, since I was in default workspace and I wanted to get logs of a pod in another namespace, just doing

```
kubectl get logs -f <pod_name>
```

was giving output "Error from server (NotFound): pods "pod_name" not found".

So I specified the namespace as well.

```
kubectl logs -f <pod_name> -n namespace
```